# Xcode - Importing STTwitter causes Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, import, linker-errors, sttwitter

Exactly what it says on the title. I've downloaded the STTwitter API several times making sure nothing went wrong with my download. I ran my project before importing the library and it runs fine.

I know there is nothing wrong with the STTwitter library because I used it in several projects, but it won't let me create another project with the import.

```
Ld /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.app/JesusWalk normal i386
    cd /Users/michaelvillar/Desktop/JesusWalk
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Intermediates/JesusWalk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.build/Objects-normal/i386/JesusWalk.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.3 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Intermediates/JesusWalk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.build/Objects-normal/i386/JesusWalk_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.app/JesusWalk

duplicate symbol _STTwitterOSErrorCode in:
    /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Intermediates/JesusWalk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.build/Objects-normal/i386/STTwitterOS.o
    /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Intermediates/JesusWalk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.build/Objects-normal/i386/STTwitterAPI.o
duplicate symbol _STTwitterAppOnlyErrorCode in:
    /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Intermediates/JesusWalk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.build/Objects-normal/i386/STTwitterAPI.o
    /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Intermediates/JesusWalk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.build/Objects-normal/i386/STTwitterAppOnly.o
duplicate symbol _STTwitterOAuthErrorCode in:
    /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Intermediates/JesusWalk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.build/Objects-normal/i386/STTwitterAPI.o
    /Users/michaelvillar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JesusWalk-evjafkmkrrhusqauysjaelfarvqn/Build/Intermediates/JesusWalk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JesusWalk.build/Objects-normal/i386/STTwitterOAuth.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please, if anyone knows something about importing the library, let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pull request may fix the issue: https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/pull/189

Please checkout the very latest version from head.